# Python Numpy - moving minimum (last N-1 values)

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

I have the follow np array:[[0,4,3,5],[4,4,3,1],[49,1,4,3],[8,4,1,6],....]

I d like to add a column that contains the min of the last 2 values (of column 3).
so column [4] would look be : [nan, nan, 1, 1]

I can't use pandas or rolling windows. I wanna compute the solution using only numpy.
TIA!

tried with generating indexes for each line and using np.minimum.accumulate

Comment: Can you give more examples of the output you expect?

Comment: gladly!
[[1,2,3,4],
 [4,3,4,1],
 [2,4,5,0],
 [1,5,4,5]]
desired output = [nan, nan, 1, 0] == mins of colum [3] last 2 elements. Instead of nan i'm ok if it's just 0's or else..

Comment: @bluearmpit gives at least 4 cases of this problem because I don't get the pattern.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: ok let's try again.
I have a array "A" of X lines. each line has 4 column. 
so let's say for line "L" I want to find:
     np.min(A[:,3][L-2:L]
I could loop through each line of the array and find last 2 value, get the min and that would be it. But i don't wanna loop as my array is too large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably something simpler, but this works:

```
a = np.array([[0,4,3,5],[4,4,3,1],[49,1,4,3],[8,4,1,6]])
b = np.array([min(a[i-2][-1],a[i-1][-1]) if i>1 else None for i in range(len(a))])
b = b.reshape(len(b), 1)
c = np.concatenate((a,b), axis=1)

# array([[0, 4, 3, 5, None],
#        [4, 4, 3, 1, None],
#        [49, 1, 4, 3, 1],
#        [8, 4, 1, 6, 1]], dtype=object)
```

To avoid a `for` loop and vectorize the workload, you can define:

```
a1 = a[:-2, -1]
a2 = a[1:-1, -1]
b = np.min((a1, a2), axis=0)
b = np.concatenate(([None, None],b))
b = b.reshape(len(b), 1)
c = np.concatenate((a,b), axis=1)
```

And if you want it compact, you can always puzzle these steps into 1 short-ish (yet barely readable) statement:

```
c = np.concatenate((a,np.concatenate(([None, None],np.min((a[:-2, -1], a[1:-1, -1]), axis=0))).reshape(len(a), 1)), axis=1)
```

Comment: i m guessing the vectorize part isn t going to work if I add line sto the array, right?

Comment: Sorry, I used the wrong axis for the `min` statement. Now it will work correctly.

Comment: the one-liner is great. amazed and grateful. Thanks!

Comment: is there anything similar that would work with a dynamic n?